# Android SwitchCompat: OnClick check programatically if switch should be triggered

Tags: android, switchcompat

I already searched a long time, but couldn't find a proper solution.
I have a `SwitchCompat` and if the user clicks on it, and REST call is fired.

I only want to switch the `SwitchCompat` when the REST-call is successful. I implemented the `onCheckedChanged()` method, but since the call is asynchronous the `SwitchCompat` get switched before I receive the response.

-> I want to check on `buttonclick` if the switch gets switched or not.

Comment: You should add your code!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options:

1. You can add your network call to `onCheckedChanged()` method, and show progress bar while making api call. After that, set state according to response.
2. You can override touch callbacks so that checkedChanged does not get called from user actions and only trigger it yourself from code.